# Power automate flow disappeared

Tags: power-automate

I am starting with the power automate.

Creating the test flow to send email when an item is added to Sharepoint list.

All seem to work, email is sent.  However next day, I come in, I do not see my flow anywhere.  I was looking for it under "My flows" and do not see it there.

I went on to the Sharepoint, added an item to the list, and see that email notification comes. So, somewhere, my flow is there. Can anyone help me find it? Even though, it was a sample I have used some features there, that I will have hard time to reproduce as I found it in the tutorial and did not have time to analyze and study it yet

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
After a while the flow appeared in "Shared with me" section .. not sure if it is related to someone adding something to it and resharing with me.